Which country is the cheapest to buy Flibxus tickets?
If I book a Flibxus ticket via flibxus.com I need to pay an extra USD 3.99 service fee per booking. I can buy the same ticket on flibxus.ie or flibxus.pt and the service fee is only € 0.99.
Is there a country that has no service fee?
I also noticed that prices may vary among countries using different currencies. It seems the difference is usually even smaller than € 1 when taking the exchange rates into account. I'm not necessarily interested in not paying service fees, but rather getting the cheapest price. In other words the "biggest bang for my buck".

Taking the exchange rate and any associated fees into account, even a ‘no service fee’ ticket might turn out to be more expensive overall

@Traveller, not if you compare prices and fees paid in euros with each other. You still have to check the ticket prices are the same, including taxes.

@André : "no service fee" and "lowest total cost" are two different criteria. Which one do you want to apply here

I edit to try and be more clear about that.

Cheapest for who? A user in the US with a US card? A user in the EU with an EU card in euros? Once you factor in exchange and foreign transaction fees (charged by the card issuer, not the merchant) it can be quite different (though difficult to generalise as each card issuer has its own fee schedule).

There are so many banks nowadays that don't charge significant Forex fees. If someone is still using a bank that charges exorbitant Forex fees when traveling, I will assume this person wouldn't care about which website to shop either. For the sake of simplicity, just assume Forex fees are insignificant.
